# pyexiv2 build error src/exiv2wrapper.hpp:32:29: error: exiv2/preview.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: python

The other day I used apt-get install python-pyexiv2 on my ubuntu server, but it seems to have given me an old version. It's not compatible with the code I wrote in my local development environment so I'd like to update it.

I downloaded the latest tar.gz from the website, extracted it and ran `scons` as per the readme. But it will not build, I get the error `src/exiv2wrapper.hpp:32:29: error: exiv2/preview.hpp: No such file or directory`

I've also user apt-get to install `libboost-python-dev` and `libexiv2-dev`

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a newer version of libexiv2-dev too.
The latest releases of pyexiv2 (≥ 0.2) require libexiv2 ≥ 0.19.
See [the developers page](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/developers.html#dependencies) for detailed instructions.